# How to create Analysis Service connection in SSIS Package

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012, ssis-2012, analysisservices

I am new to Analysis service in SSIS. And During the creation of `New Analysis Service Connection` in SSIS, After having all the SQL-Server credentials, Test connection is getting failed. Also, it's database name not getting appear. Is there any predefined things that I need create before making this connection.

---

What I am Doing is??

1. Right Click on connection Panel and clicked on `New Connection`.
2. Appeared below image and clicked on `MSOLAP 100`

[image]

3. Then I have set up for the Credentials for Database but showing some error and Database Panel is also getting blank like below image.

[image]

4. Error Message while testing the connection.
   [image]

**Can anyone please help, to get out of this?
Suggestions are welcome.**

Comment: I see you have typed in the server name but not the location? I don't think it can find it just by the name. If you are working on your pc it must be something like "localhost"

Comment: @Bonzay: I have just tried, but still same problem. I have updated an second Image.

Comment: @Bonzai: But yes it is not my local machine. So is it okay to use "localhost"?

Comment: hmmm i just tested it in my environment. Using the server's name or IP must do the job. Try to connect directly to the ssas server using the management studio to test your credentials.

Comment: Ohh yeah!!. @Bonzay. Thanks a lot. It worked. Actually I was giving credentials of Database Engine. But now I have changed it to SSAS. thanks :)